# Windows Metro C++ C# - How to add namespace of WinRT Portable Project?

Tags: c#, c++, microsoft-metro

I am working on a Windows C++ Metro App, where I've added a separate portable project in C# to the solution.

When adding the namespace to the project the namespace is underlined in red, and hovering upon the namespace states: "Error: name must be a namespace name".

I am currently wondering how to resolve the namespace error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly add the portable project as a reference in the C++ project.  This will allow the namespace to be discovered properly, and should eliminate the error.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Ultimate, and building Metro app for Windows/Windows Phone 8. How can I reference that project?

Comment: @user812954 Open up the project properties for the C++ project, and go to the references section.  You can add a reference to the other project there.